# Websphere Application Server v9.0 supported with which version of Rational Application Developer?

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad, wasapi

can someone help me, I'm trying to work with Websphere Application Server 9.0 but I need to work on IBM Rational Application Developer IDE for the use of sqlj. I tried to install IBM Rational Application Developer IDE version 8.0 but Websphere Application Server 9.0 is not supported with this IDE. Do I need to install IBM Rational Application Developer 9.0 IDE to work with Websphere Application Server 9.0? Or is there any other IDE that supports Websphere Application Server 9.0 and sqlj scripts both.

Answer (score 0):

According this [IBM KnowledgeCenter for IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.6.1/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/rad_overview.html), it looks like RAD v9.6 is the lowest version to support Websphere Application Server 9.0.